# ASP.NET-MVC 3 force log for every page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I'm new to ASP.NET and not the most experienced of programmers.

I have recently been introduced to ASP.NET-MVC 3 for an application I'd like to build.

I have the basic functionality down but am not to familiar with the login.

The built-in login works for what I want (just something simple), but I want to ensure that a login must be used before any of the actual functionality appears.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller you should make use of the Authorize attribute, this forces the authorization before doing the decorated action.

For instance, in your home controller add the following `[Authorize]` as such

```
[Authorize]
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Also you can decorate an entire controller which will force ALL methods to be authroized prior to being used, as such:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```